# Rstudio won't interpret latex/RMarkDown

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I've had a functioning RStudio setup for a while, on a Manjaro machine.
But suddenly it seems to no longer to able to interpret latex code. (Or is this an RMarkdown issue?). When I try to Knitr a pdf, I now get the following error message in the 'render' window:

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r`  in Labb2New.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Labb2New.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Labb2New.log for more info.
Execution halted

What could be the issue here?
I've done no installation or updates (that I'm aware of) since Rstudio last worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of ways that you can compile Latex inside RMarkdown in RStudio, it can be confusing... so personally I did this:

Be sure to install everything in **ONE SINGLE USER** and **not** in the system, it could cause directory conflict and MiKtex somehow doesn't work for the whole systems, i read other comments where they can't solve that problem, me neither xD.

You should have all this requirements

1. R (you already installed it)
2. [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)
3. [MikTex](https://miktex.org/download)
4. [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

   ### Install from CRAN

   install.extras(repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

THEN

```
## Install from CRAN
install.packages('rmarkdown')
```

Everything should work, you should have enough space memory to do this though. I just had this exact same problem yesterday so i reviewed my history x3

anyway if you have other problem with this process please feel free to tell me, be sure to read the documentations for what I listed there's lots of requirements inside, so probably is that!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the install of MikTex just freezes halfway, and the TexLive install won't start..

Comment: could you add some details to that? of what exactly did you do? messages shown? TeXLive weighted the most (1.2GB) so it took a bit to install you need TeXLive for the pdf conversion to knit "[pdfTeX](https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/)", it also contains the essential packages to have everything without error.

Also if you read the requirements somewhere in there should appear pandoc("a universal document converter") you can find it [here](https://pandoc.org/installing.html)

Comment: about MikTeK remember to not have conflicting versions*, if you have an old install in the whole system, install it again in one single user, and do the installation with admin priveleges.


then after you installed it check updates and update MiKteK

*with this I mean install MikTek from Miktek itself(from the link I gave you) and not TeXWorks (it's deprecated and just causes conflicts) AND not 2 different number version ofc